# Stacked Bar Plot in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, bar-chart

I've looked at the similar questions on here regarding stacked bar plots in R, but I'm still not having any luck.

I have created the following data frame:

```
        A   B   C   D   E   F    G
     1 480 780 431 295 670 360  190
     2 720 350 377 255 340 615  345
     3 460 480 179 560  60 735 1260
     4 220 240 876 789 820 100   75
```

A:G represents the x-axis and the y-axis would be duration (seconds). 
How would I go about stacking the following data in R?

Thank you very much in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The dataset:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "A   B   C   D   E   F    G
1 480 780 431 295 670 360  190
2 720 350 377 255 340 615  345
3 460 480 179 560  60 735 1260
4 220 240 876 789 820 100   75", header = TRUE)
```

Now you can convert the data frame into a matrix and use the `barplot` function.

```
barplot(as.matrix(dat))
```

[image]

Answer (score 38):

A somewhat different approach using ggplot2:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "A   B   C   D   E   F    G
1 480 780 431 295 670 360  190
2 720 350 377 255 340 615  345
3 460 480 179 560  60 735 1260
4 220 240 876 789 820 100   75", header = TRUE)

library(reshape2)

dat$row <- seq_len(nrow(dat))
dat2 <- melt(dat, id.vars = "row")

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat2, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = row)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  xlab("\nType") +
  ylab("Time\n") +
  guides(fill = FALSE) +
  theme_bw()
```

this gives:

[image]

When you want to include a legend, delete the `guides(fill = FALSE)` line.

Answer (score 11):

I'm obviosly not a very good R coder, but if you wanted to do this with ggplot2:

```
data<- rbind(c(480, 780, 431, 295, 670, 360,  190),
             c(720, 350, 377, 255, 340, 615,  345),
             c(460, 480, 179, 560,  60, 735, 1260),
             c(220, 240, 876, 789, 820, 100,   75))

a <- cbind(data[, 1], 1, c(1:4))
b <- cbind(data[, 2], 2, c(1:4))
c <- cbind(data[, 3], 3, c(1:4))
d <- cbind(data[, 4], 4, c(1:4))
e <- cbind(data[, 5], 5, c(1:4))
f <- cbind(data[, 6], 6, c(1:4))
g <- cbind(data[, 7], 7, c(1:4))

data           <- as.data.frame(rbind(a, b, c, d, e, f, g))
colnames(data) <-c("Time", "Type", "Group")
data$Type      <- factor(data$Type, labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = data, aes(x = Type, y = Time, fill = Group)) + 
       geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
       opts(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]