# R: How to make histogram basing on the values in the other column as well?

Tags: r, plot, histogram

Let's say I have a large dataset consisting of two columns.

The first one mentions different people (marking them with their name), while the second one is just a binary variable marking if a person mentioned in the first column was met in another dataset (it doesn't matter now in which one).

So I have something like this:

```
Name       Found

Peter      0

John       1

Peter      1

Mark       0

Peter      0
```

and so on.

I'd like to make a histogram representing:
1) the overall frequency for each name;
2) but the chart representing each name would be split into two parts by colour: found vs unfound. Something like this, actually: https://www.flickr.com/photos/gommit/6748028567, but having only two colours.

What's the best way to do so?

Comment: Check out `barplot()` What you are describing is a stacked bar chart, rather than a histogram.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stacked Bar Plot in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349929/stacked-bar-plot-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is in a dataframe called `df`, you could use `table` and `barplot` to do something like:

```
barplot(table(df$Found, df$Name))
```

[image]