# R: Stacked bar plot with barpot, ggplot or plotly

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I've been searching to find a solution, but none of the already existing questions fit my problem.

I have a data.frame:

```
Pat <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2)
V_ID <- c(1,1,6,6,9,9,1,1,6,6,9,9)
T_ID <- c("A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B", "A","B")
apples <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
bananas <- c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
cranberries <- c(3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)

df <- data.frame(Pat,V_ID, T_ID, apples, bananas, cranberries)
```

I am trying to plot:

```
barplot(as.matrix(df[,4:6]) ,
    main="tobefound", horiz = FALSE,width = 1, 
    names.arg=colnames(df[,4:6]),
    las=2,
    col = c("blue", "red"),
    legend = df[,3],
    args.legend = list(x="topleft"),
    beside= FALSE)
```

**BARPLOT**

[image]

I need two changes: 
First of all I like to have all "B"s (so the red part in every stack) piled up together and then the blue ones on top. Second: is there a way of decreasing the legend to only A and B once besides addressing this via

```
legend = df[1:2,3],
```

I am also looking for a solution using plotly or ggplot.

Thanks,

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349929/stacked-bar-plot-in-r?rq=1) what you're looking for?

Comment: nope. Looked at your suggestion before. My goal is to have all "A"s and "B"s piled up together by colour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First reshape:

```
df_long <- tidyr::gather(df, 'key', 'value', apples:cranberries)
```

Then plot:

```
ggplot(df_long, aes(key, value, fill = T_ID)) + geom_col(col = 'black')
```

[image]

Or perhaps without the borders:

```
ggplot(df_long, aes(key, value, fill = T_ID)) + geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

Using base graphics, you needed to sort `df` by `T_ID` first.

```
df = df[order(df$T_ID), ]

barplot(as.matrix(df[,4:6]) ,
        main="tobefound", horiz = FALSE,width = 1, 
        names.arg=colnames(df[,4:6]),
        las=2,
        ylim = c(0,40),
        col = 1+as.numeric(as.factor(df$T_ID)),
        border = NA,
        beside= FALSE)

box()
legend('topleft', fill = 1+as.numeric(as.factor(levels(df$T_ID))), legend = levels(as.factor(df$T_ID)))
```

[image]