# creating stacked bar chart in r

Tags: r, bar-chart, stacked-area-chart

I am really struggeling with creating a stacked bar chart in R. I am quite a beginner so even with looking at other examples I couldn't get to the right solution. 
Here is how my data looks like:

```
         gdp_2      def_2      pcom_2      ff_2       nbr_2        tr_2    unemp_2
[1,] 0.02938106 0.01009107 0.014915879 0.9456120 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.00000000
[2,] 0.04824422 0.02513049 0.016115796 0.8303659 0.002320698 0.001255257 0.07656760
[3,] 0.06532489 0.05206917 0.011290059 0.7623530 0.002604175 0.008032572 0.09832613
[4,] 0.07485907 0.07576441 0.009215843 0.7064166 0.003207812 0.008397380 0.12213887
[5,] 0.07894689 0.10131343 0.007674296 0.6635104 0.003415185 0.009705830 0.13543392
```

The numbers 1 to 5 on the left hand side indicate time horizons. So I would like to stack for each time horizon all the values for the variables gdp_2, def_2, pcom_2, ff_2, nbr_2, tr_2 and unemp_2.

This should look kind of like this [image: stacked bar chart]

Of course it would be nice to have a nice legend but at the moment I really do not even know how to create the stacked bar chart.
By the way, for those interested in the topic: It is a forecast error variance decomposition of economic variables of the US.

I thank you so much already in advance!
Best,
Rico

Comment: Please check out this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349929/stacked-bar-plot-in-r

Comment: Thanks for your comment to my question! I have already had a look at this but unfortunately I was not able to apply it to my data since I am really a beginner in R. Nevertheless, thank you that you took your time to answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ggplot2`, `dplyr` and `tidyr` (all parts of `tidyverse`)...

```
library(tidyverse)

chart <- df %>% mutate(year=1:n()) %>% #add year as a column to your df
  gather(key=colname,value=value,-year) %>% #convert to long format
  ggplot(aes(x=year,y=value,fill=colname)) + #send to ggplot
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="stack") #draw stacked bar

print(chart)
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Andew Gustar
Thanks a lot for your answer. In your example, it looks perfect! This is exactly what I would like. However, when I try to do it with my own data I get the error message:
Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'double', 'numeric')"

Comment: Dear @Andrew Gustar
Thanks a lot, I just had to change my data that it is a dataframe and it worked perfectly now!!! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: That's what I was about to suggest!  Glad you got it sorted.