# How to create stacked histogram from two numeric variables in R?

Tags: r, histogram

I'm working with R for the first time and I came to a problem a can't solve.

I measured the "working time" and the "study time" of students. Together they result in the "workload" of the students. I would like to create a histogram that depicts the workload and differentiates color between working hours and study time.

Just like a stacked barplot, but as histogram, without any categorical variable.

I searched the internet for a long time, but I did only find stacked barplots, overlapping histograms or densityplots.

Your help will be highly appriciated

Edit: My Data looks like

```
    VP     Work   Study     Workload
     1     10     20        30
     2     30     20        50
     3     20     40        60
     ...   ...    ...
```

So the bars of the Histogram shoul have a hights of 30, 50 and 60 an be proportional colored for "work" and "study".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stacked Bar Plot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349929/stacked-bar-plot-in-r)

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your edit, I assuming that you want one bar for each student with their total hours. Something like this?

I am using `ggplot2` and functions from `tidyverse` packages.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- tibble(VP = 1:3,
             Work = c(10, 30, 20),
             Study = c(20, 20, 40),
             Workload = c(30, 50, 60)) # Or simply `Workload = Work + Study`

df %>% 
  select(-Workload) %>% 
  tidyr::gather(-VP, key = "type", value = "time") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(VP), y = time, fill = type)) +
    geom_col(position = "stack") # `position` argument defines the stacked bars
```

[image]

Comment: Your assumption is right and your code worked out well. Thank you very well for your efford. Do you now, if the bars can also be sorted according to the length of the workload variable?

Comment: Use the `reorder()` function in your `ggplot(data, aes(x = ...), ...)` call: replace `factor(VP)` by `reorder(factor(VP), time)` or `reorder(factor(VP), desc(time))` (for ascending or descending order, respectively). And always click on the button "Accept answer" if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you!
From now on I think of the button. That was my first question here, I hope I will improve over time.